# How to validate email using jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My script javascript is like this :

```
email: {
         required: true,
         email: true          
},
```

When in the textfield email, I write : `chelsea@gmail` without `.com`, it's valid.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: as per jquery-validation plugin this should work. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: i had this problem you just change like this name filed email_field: {
         required: true,
         email: true          
},

Comment: `admin@localhost` is an example of email address without `.com .org .net`

Comment: As per the [version 1.12 changelog](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/changelog.md#1120--2014-04-01), the jQuery Validate plugin is now following the HTML5 regex for a valid email address, which no longer requires a TLD.

Answer (score 15):

### Edited Answer:

To validate whether an email address is of the `name@domain.tld` format you can use the following regular expression:

```
var emailExp = new RegExp(/^\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i);
```

This regular expression accepts only email addresses that contain an @-sign, a dot and a 2-4 characters long TLD.

You can use the above regular expression to validate a given email address as shown below:

```
function validate_email (email) {
   /* Define the recommended regular expression. */
   var emailExp = new RegExp(/^\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i);

   /* Test the email given against the expression and return the result. */
   return emailExp.test(email);
}
```

**jQuery Validator:**

jQuery Validator doesn't support the use of regular expressions and instead uses the default HTML5 email regular expression internally, so you must first create a new method for the validator that does that:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    /* The value you can use inside the email object in the validator. */
    "regex",

    /* The function that tests a given string against a given regEx. */
    function(value, element, regexp)  {
        /* Check if the value is truthy (avoid null.constructor) & if it's not a RegEx. (Edited: regex --> regexp)*/

        if (regexp && regexp.constructor != RegExp) {
           /* Create a new regular expression using the regex argument. */
           regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
        }

        /* Check whether the argument is global and, if so set its last index to 0. */
        else if (regexp.global) regexp.lastIndex = 0;

        /* Return whether the element is optional or the result of the validation. */
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    }
);
```

Now that a method supporting validation against a regular expression was created for the validator, you can use the `jQuery.validate` as follows:

```
$('#element_id').validate({
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        regex: /^\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i
    }
});
```

---

### Original Answer *(Improved)*:

To filter an email address and only accept a format like `name@domain.tld` use this regular expression:

```
var emailExp = new RegExp(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i);
```

This regular expression filters out any "junk" that may be entered and requires that an @-sign, a dot and a 2-4 characters long TLD be present. If a substring of the given email address matches it the substring is returned, otherwise `false`.

You can use the above regular expression to filter a given email address as shown below:

```
function filter_email (email) {
   var
      /* Define the recommended regular expression. */
      emailExp = new RegExp(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i),

      /* Use 'match' to filter the email address given and cache the result. */
      filtered = email.match(emailExp);

   /* Return the filtered value or false. */
   return filtered ? filtered[0] : false;
}
```

---

### Notes:

- *When answering the OP's question more than a year ago, I mistook his intention for email validation as an attempt to filter a given string keeping only a substring of it that is an email address.*
- *This answer considers addresses lacking a TLD invalid even though they are perfectly valid in the real world as per OP's request.*

Comment: Where the script was added? I use jquery validate

Comment: @mosestoh I edited the answer.

Comment: This answer would also validates `test@test.com,test2@test.com` as true, although its not valid.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Adam! When I wrote this answer a year plus ago, I mistook the OP's request for `email filtering` rather than `email validation`. Apparently, my answer was serving a different purpose, so I edited to correct that. I hope you find it useful. _Thanks a lot for your comment_.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#login-form").validate({
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {         
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});   });
```

i hope it will be helpful

https://jsfiddle.net/dave17/bex78vvs/

Comment: I using jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.14.0. It's not working

Answer (score 1):

```
var re=new RegExp();
    re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;

if(re.test(Email_Value)){
   alert("valid email");
}
```